# Add maven project to m2 folder in intellij idea after build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans, build

Add project to m2 folder after build in Netbeans. Is there such a feature in Intellij idea that save in the m2 folder after build?

Comment: Your title and question are not in line. You want to add to m2 or not?

Comment: I corrected. I want to add

Comment: How do you build your project exactly? If you're doing mvn install, what you build will be published in .m2. However, if you do mvn compile, you only compile locally and if you do mvn package, you only compile + create the .jar.

Comment: I create maven project in intellij. And i do   mvn compile. But it doesn't add my project to m2 folder.

Comment: Because mvn compile only compiles the source code. Then you have mvn package, which compiles and creates a jar. And then you have mvn install, which packages and adds the jar to the local repository (.m2). You may want to try mvn install instead of mvn compile.

Comment: P.s. your question is unrelated to the IDEs (IntelliJ or Netbeans), it's rather related to how Maven works.

Comment: Yes. Resolved problem. I don't mvn install. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `mvn install` to install to `~/.m2`